# Reactive form set value of a select input

Tags: angular, forms

I'm trying to autofill the select input. 
When the form opens the value of the select is not filled, here is my code.

I have a static array of objects (`extensions`) where the user can select from. This array is of `CountryCode[]` type.

**view.component.ts**

```
<form [formGroup]='form' autocomplete="off">
...
   <select class="form-control" formControlName='cellExtInput'>

       <option *ngFor="let ext of extensions" [ngValue]="ext">
          ({{ ext.callingCode }}) {{ ext.name }}
       </option>

   </select>
...
</form>
```

**controller.component.ts**

```
export interface CountryCode {
  id: any,
  code3l: any,
  code2l: any,
  name: any,
  flag: any,
  callingCode: any,
}

async ngOnInit() {    


    // Initialize form
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      ...      
      cellExtInput: new FormControl(''),
    });

    var controls = this.form.controls;

    var code : CountryCode = {
      id: "131",
      code3l: "PRT",
      code2l: "PT",
      name: "Portugal",
      flag: "http://flags.fmcdn.net/data/flags/w580/pt.png",
      callingCode: "+351"
    }

    controls.cellExtInput.setValue(code, {onlySelf: true});

    ......
}
```

Comment: please clarify what is not working i.e. what you mean by " I can't manage to get it right"

Comment: @AndrewAllen since I specify the .setValue() on onInit(), when the form opens the select option is not filled.

Comment: Try ```<select class="form-control" formControlName='cellExtInput'>

       <option *ngFor="let ext of extensions" [value]="ext.name" [selected]="ext.name === code.name">
          ({{ ext.callingCode }}) {{ ext.name }}
       </option>

   </select>```

Comment: I think you're having issues too because the `ngValue` you're specifying is an object rather than a primitive type and the `<option>` takes values of primitive types

Comment: @haron68 Please, submit this answer so I can mark it as correct. I only changed [ngValue] to [Value]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
   <select class="form-control" formControlName='cellExtInput'>

       <option *ngFor="let ext of extensions" [value]="ext">
          ({{ ext.callingCode }}) {{ ext.name }}
       </option>

   </select>
```

I think you're having issues with the `ngValue`. You're specifying an object for it rather than a primitive type and the `<option>` takes values of primitive types.

As described on [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp)

> **Attribute** | **Value** | **Description**
>
> disabled | disabled | Specifies that an option should be disabled
>
> label | text | Specifies a shorter label for an option
>
> selected | selected |  Specifies that an option should be pre-selected when the page 
>   loads
>
> value |    text |  Specifies the value to be sent to a server

**Note:** OP only changed `[ngValue]` to `[value]` in their code.

Comment: You don't need `[selected]` if you are using the `formControlName` directive. The selected value will be set based on the state in the form group.